# В этом случае объект очищается из-за алгоритма Mark-and-sweep или это просто эффект работы локальной переменной, в которую он был помещен?

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, сборщик-мусора, variable

Я не понимаю о чем конкретно идет [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_mark-and-sweep) речь:

```js
function f() {
    let a = 'some text';
    var obj1 = {};
    var obj2 = {};
    obj1.p = obj2; // obj1 references obj2
    obj2.p = obj1; // obj2 references obj1. This creates a cycle.
}
f();
```

> Теперь циклические ссылки - не проблема.
> В вышеприведённом первом примере после возврата из функции оба объекта не имеют на себя никаких ссылок, доступных из глобального объекта. Соответственно, сборщик мусора пометит их как недоступные и затем удалит.

Я не понимаю что является причиной тому, что объект удалился - алгоритм или просто работа локальной переменной, в которую объект был помещен (локальная переменная доступна только во время работы функции - также получается и с объектом)?

Грубо говоря, я не понимаю смысл этого примера. Локальные переменные (!!!в которые не были помещены объекты) тоже удаляются после окончания работы функции, но алгоритм тут не причём).

Comment: Локальные **переменные** - удаляются, а вот **объекты**, на которые указывали эти переменные, продолжают жить в памяти до тех пор, пока до них не доберётся mark-and-sweep. И не имеет значения, были ли эти объекты в локальных переменных или где-нибудь ещё

Comment: Вы путаете разные уровни абстракции, условно говоря, логическую и физическую модели. Локальные и глобальные переменные - это все логический уровень. А сборщик мусора работает глубже - на физическом, и не знает, локальная это переменная, или глобальная. Для него все просто, счетчик ссылок на переменную равен 0 - можно удалять. А вот для поиска тех переменных, где этот счетчик не 0, но удалять все равно можно, и нужен этот самый алгоритм. Вот как-то так, если очень грубо.

Comment: @Yaant современные js-движки не используют счетчик ссылок

Comment: @andreymal да, но статья по ссылке говорит о Mark-and-sweep в том контексте, что он решает те проблемы, с которыми не справляется подсчет ссылок. Вот я и попытался сказать об этом же другими словами. :)

Comment: @Yaant то есть получается, что в примере выше при работе алгоритма подсчета ссылок объекты внутри функции не удалялись бы, потому что на них все еще есть ссылки? Если, как написал `@andreymal` _...объекты, на которые указывали эти переменные, продолжают жить в памяти до тех пор, пока до них не доберётся mark-and-sweep. И не имеет значения, были ли эти объекты в локальных переменных или где-нибудь ещё._ Правильно ли я понимаю?

Comment: @andreymal а что тогда отвечает за удаление обычных переменных (которые содержат в себе примитив)? Как я понимаю, за удаление объектов отвечает алгоритм Mark-and-sweep, что отвечает за удаление таких вот переменных?

Comment: @Ivan Ага, правильно. А вообще, по вашей же ссылке написано: _"все современные веб-браузеры оснащаются сборщиками мусора, работающими исключительно по принципу mark-and-sweep"_, это универсальный алгоритм, он заменяет подсчет ссылок.

Comment: Кажется, с примитивами всё сложно и запутанно и у всех всё по-разному. Если я правильно понимаю [этот пост](https://medium.com/@stankoja/v8-bug-hunting-part-2-memory-representation-of-js-types-ea37571276b8), в движке V8 целые 32-битные числа изначально хранятся прямо в стеке (и, соответственно, сборщиком мусора не обслуживаются), а как только перестают влезать в 32 бита, переезжают из стека в кучу и преобразуются из целого числа в вещественное.